# Форма ввода телефона

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, bootstrap

Как сделать таково вида форму ввода телефона?
Достаточно ли использовать только bootstrap?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например можно дополнительно использовать плагин - [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

```js
$(".phone").mask("+7(999)999-9999");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
  
  <input type="text" class="phone">
```

Answer (score 3):

Советую использовать [Phone Input из bootstrap form helpers](http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/phone.html) (нужен JQuery). Тогда html поля ввода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium bfh-phone" data-format="+7 (ddd) ddd-dd-dd">
```